# What is the significance behind having small kernel sizes over having one large kernel size that covers the entire input in a CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, convolution, filter

I have hardly ever seen anyone cover the entire input image with a filter of the same dimensions. I was wondering why that is the case, and if the performance in say, an image detection application would decrease if someone used kernel size = the size of the input image itself?

Comment: The idea of CNN is a representation learning, there is a larger space to capture new representation by using smaller kernel size, compare to a kernel that matches image size.

Comment: Would this be functionally different from a fully-connected layer?

Comment: Would it? @user253751 That's actually a neat way to frame the question as well